# Компонент рендерится 2 раза || React

Tags: reactjs, redux, hook

У меня есть компонент который рендерится два раза. Скорее всего это из за хука useEffect. Я оставлю скрин с этим компонентом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

setPostsRequest это асинхронный экшен, который отправляет запрос в БД, получает массив, и присваивает его в store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый рендер происходит на основании данных по умолчанию в useState или селекторе как я полагаю в вашем случае.

После этого активируется useEffect, который обновляет state и из-за новых данных в state происходит второй рендер.

В этом нет ничего плохого.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать